# How to fix the error I am getting while loading the Facebook javascript-sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am loading the Facebook javascript sdk into my page using the following code:-

```
           (function() {
            console.log('Hello World! From self executing function.'); 
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.async = true;
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            console.log('javascript sdk is appended into the fb-root element of the page.');
        }());
```

It is getting loaded properly but I am getting the following error in my console:-

```
  Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
  [Break On This Error]     

   ...5(i(ca.getElementsByTagName('*')),'forEach',true,function(ka){if(!ea&&ka.getAttr...
```

How to fix this?

Any help will be thankfully recieved ?

Comment: Which browser do you get this error ? it's seems like there is no errors for me when adding this script under chrome.

Comment: I am using FireFox right now. Okay I will check in Chrome also. @Adidi I am using the javascript code from a tutorial at http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/.

Comment: @Adidi I also am not gettting any error in chrome. So it is just a browser specific issue.

Comment: I don't get any error in Firefox as well. The main thing you need to check is that the facebook script is indeed loaded and you can continue using it and call the API.

Comment: How to check that, but it is getting loaded as I am able to log the user and get his Facebook name and Facebook profile photo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook javascript SDK normally causes cross browser issues. For resolving this issue, facebook itself had integrated a method, i.e. by adding a channel url during FB.init() function.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
  status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

 };
```

Adding a channel file resolves the cross browser issues.

The contents of the channel.html file should be just a single line:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

The channelUrl parameter within FB.init() is optional, but strongly recommended. Providing a channel file can help address three specific known issues.

- Pages that include code to communicate across frames may cause Social
  Plugins to show up as blank without a channelUrl.
- If no channelUrl is provided and a page includes auto-playing audio
  or video, the user may hear two streams of audio because the page has
  been loaded a second time in the background for cross domain
  communication.
- A channel file will prevent inclusion of extra hits in your
  server-side logs. If you do not specify a channelUrl, you should
  remove page views containing fb_xd_bust or fb_xd_fragment parameters
  from your logs to ensure proper counts.

The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL matching the page on which you include the SDK. In other words, the channel file domain must include www if your site is served using www, and if you modify document.domain on your page you must make the same document.domain change in the channel.html file as well.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/